# Use webview to display 00a0

Tags: android, webview

I'm displaying text/html in a WebView.  How do I get it to display \u00A0 as a non blank space?  Instead it's showing Â (which happens to 00C2).

Here's a snip of code:

```
String s = "Line of text with A0 here:\u00A0.";
WebView v = (WebView)findViewById (R.id.html);
v.loadData(s, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

I realize I can use replace() on the string, but I was hoping to avoid additional processing.

Comment: The problem could well be that `\u00A0` is UTF-16, not UTF-8. However you could just use the HTML entity `&nbsp;` instead of `\u00A0` which is much clearer.

Comment: I actually did try UTF-16 as well.  No different.

Comment: Check the documentation, you need to base64 or URL encode the string. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: It's definitely not base64.  It might be utf-8, but WebView isn't displaying it correctly with that param.

Comment: @PeriHartman thats what I am trying to say. If you have already a String, specifying an encoding does not make sense. If you look into the docu you see the encoding parameter can only be used to distinguish between base64 and URL encoding. So you need to encode your string in either of these before you pass it to the `loadData` method.

Comment: @henry - I'm reading email, thus I don't have an option to change the string's encoding.  The code snip I provided was just to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @PeriHartman You can always URL encode a string, no matter where it came from.

Comment: Wouldn't it be cheaper to just do a string replace on the 00A0?  Or am I going to run into other char encoding problems later?